# Problems with Octave on Windows 8: crashes after any error

Tags: windows-8, octave

I have installed (and re-installed) Octave 3 times on Windows 8, and I still can't get it right.  The first and most obvious problem is that the prompt is missing; the screen only shows the flashing underscore that follows the prompt.  This is not a major problem since the system properly responds to commands.

**The major problem is that Octave crashes whenever it encounters a syntax error**, instead of politely giving a diagnostic.  This makes for extremely tedious software development.

Is there a way around this problem, or do we just have to wait for one side or the other to come up with an accommodation?

Comment: I wanted to share another alternative I found, namely web octave.
Here is the URL: https://octave-online.net/

Answer (score 22):

I encountered the same problem. I solved it by this:
create a shortcut to octave.exe, then right click->property-> change the "target" to something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Octave\Octave3.6.*_gcc*.*.*\bin\octave.exe -i --line-editing
```

Then it won't exit if u have syntax errors.
I don't understand the meaning of the parameters yet.

reference:
http://exciton.eo.yzu.edu.tw/~lab/?p=1121

Comment: This C:\Program Files\Octave\Octave3.6.*_gcc*.*.* points at your installation folder. f.e. mine was: D:\Octave-3.6.4 default it is C:\Program Files\Octave\Octave-3.6.4

Comment: look at [this](http://youneedtoprogram.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/installing-octave-3-6-4-on-windows-8/).

Comment: Is `--line-editing` necessary?  The problem is fixed by simply adding `-i` as a command line argument.

Comment: in my case only `-i` parameter was sufficient. But my default path to bin folder is `C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin` so i recommend to add only `-i` parameter at the end of edited shortcut or start Octave from command prompt by typing in bin folder  `octave -i`

Answer (score 8):

Type *octave --help* can check the meaning of parameters.
-i also --interactvie, to force Octave interactive behavior. 
Maybe Octave run at non-interactive mode at default, that means prompt should not be shown and it should terminate immediately when encountered error when reading a file.

Comment: (+1) This is exactly right.  All that is needed is the `-i` argument upon startup, which can be added to a shortcut as Tyler explains in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, or if this is too bloated of a solution for you, but I use Octave on Windows 7 through Cygwin without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get Octave to run on Windows 8, you may consider running Octave through Linux via computer virtualization technology (virtual computer). Two, off the top of my head that you could use are [VirtualBox by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html%20or%20VMWare%20player) or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player)
Once you have it installed, you can go to any number of sites that have pre-built Linux images that you can download and then run inside of Windows 8.X. Do a Google search of for 'Virtualbox images' or as 'VMWare appliances'. You can then download and use that to run the lastest version of Octave. I hope that helps.

Cheers,